# Swagger documentation not properly representing uppercase fields

Tags: java, json, xml, api, swagger

I'm having a peculiar problem where leading uppercase characters are being presented as lowercase in swagger. (also, API recognized the uppercase for XML requests, but not for JSON requests)

Controller:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@ApiOperation(value = "value", notes = "notes", response = UpdateResponse.class, tags = {})

@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful Response", response = UpdateResponse.class)
})
@RequestMapping(value = "/search",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<UpdateResponse> search(
        @ApiParam(value = "value", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Request1 request1) {

    UpdateResponse response = new UpdateResponse(request1.getIdentifier());

    return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Input Request Bean:

```
@lombok.ToString
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.Data
@ApiModel(description = "description.")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request1")
public class Request1 {

    @XmlElement(name="Identifier")
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    @Valid
    private String identifier;
}
```

Swagger JSON representation (the API recognizes the "identifer" tag):

```
{
  "identifier": "string"
}
```

Swagger XML representation (the API does NOT recognize the "identifier" tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request1>
    <identifier>string</identifier>
</Request1>
```

I need the API to recognize the following JSON request, and I need swagger to generate it:

```
{
  "Identifier": "string"
}
```

And I need the API to recognize the following XML request, and I need swagger to generate it as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request1>
    <Identifier>string</Identifier>
</Request1>
```

What do I need to do to make the API understand the uppercase "Identifier" json tag, and what do I need to do for swagger to generate it properly for both XML and JSON?

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix, all I have to do is put @JsonProperty("Identifier") on top the field:

```
@lombok.ToString
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.Data
@ApiModel(description = "description.")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request1")
public class Request1 {

    @XmlElement(name="Identifier")
    @JsonProperty("Identifier") // <-- missing json property annotation added
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    @Valid
    private String identifier;
}
```